# Google Script - Email - Html for loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have recently been working on a script to send an email from a google spreadsheet when one or more values in a certain column are changed.

Below my email function:

```
function sendEmail(list){
  var recipient="emaild@gmail.com";
  var subject="Multiples prices have changed";
  var body = "";
  for(var i=0; i<list.length;i++){ // Get throught the list to write the body
    body=body + list[i][0] + " price has changed by " + list[i][1] + "\%\n";
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```

> list[i][0]

return the product title

> list[i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8ZCx.png)

return the Δ%

So, The email body that I riceve is only text, I.e.:

```
product 1 price has changed by 20%
product 2 price has changed by 5%
product 3 price has changed by 15%
```

**I would like to inset a bit of style in order to riceve an email body like this:**

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function sendEmail(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var list=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var recipient="emaild@gmail.com";
  var subject="Multiples prices have changed";
  var html='<style>td{border:px solid black;}#td1{font-size:22;color:black;font-weight:bold;}#td2{font-size:16;color:red;}{</style><table>';
  for(var i=0; i<list.length;i++){ 
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td id="td1">%s</td></tr><tr><td id="td2">%s</td></tr>',list[i][0],`${list[i][1]} ${list[i][2]}.`);
  }
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject,'',{htmlBody: html});
  //var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Price Changes')
}
```

Here's what my spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

And here's the CSV of my data:

```
Product,Direction,Amount
Product1,price has increased ,10
Product2,price has increased ,20
Product3,price has increased ,30
Product4,price has increased ,40
Product5,price has increased ,50
Product6,price has increased ,60
```